# Animation details in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm new to Android animation, i want to know the details for Android animation. Shall anyone tell me what are the way to create an animation in android?

And, What type of animations are available in android. Where can i study that? And, if anybody having some examples mean, give here.

Best Regards - SPK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to initiate about animation is [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html), [Here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/) and [Here](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of great information in the standard Android documentation.  You can find all the information you are looking for [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/) could be your answer

Comment: Please don't post a single link as an answer, elaborate it. What happens when the link stops working? We often delete single link answers.